# Passing values to jqGrid custom function for validation of duplicate rows

Tags: jqgrid

I have a jqGrid function as follows in an ASP.NET MVC using Razor

```
$(function () {
    $("#grid").jqGrid({
        url: "/Common/GetCategoryList",
        editurl: '/Common/CategoryEdit',
        datatype: 'json',
        mtype: 'Get',
        colNames: ['Id', 'Name', 'Created On', 'Status'],
        colModel: [
            { key: true, name: 'id', editable: false, formatter: 'integer', viewable: false, hidden: true },
            {
                key: false,
                name: 'name',
                editable: true,
                editrules: { custom: true, custom_func: checkforduplicates, required:true }

            },
```

I then have a custom function to check for duplicate names in the above grid

```
function checkforduplicates(value, colname) {
    var grid = $("#grid");

    var textsLength = grid.jqGrid("getGridParam", "data"),myName = $.map(textsLength, function (item) { return item.name });
    alert("textsLength is " + textsLength);
    alert(JSON.stringify(myName));
    var textsLength2 = JSON.stringify(textsLength);
    alert("textsLength 2 is " + textsLength2);


    var myAttrib = $.map(textsLength,
        function (item) { return item.name });
    alert("myAttrib is " + myAttrib);

    var count = 0;
    for (var k in textsLength) {
        if (textsLength.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
            ++count;
        }
    }

    var text, i;
    alert("value of count is " + count);

    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        text = myAttrib[i];
        if (value === text) {
            return [false, " - Duplicate category name."];
        }
    }
    return [true, ""];
}
```

All the alerts above return empty values. So the function is not getting values from the grid even though there are more than 20 rows, and i enter a duplicate value and click submit.

**EDIT:-**
When I use grid.jqGrid("getGridParam", "data") where the datatype is "local" instead of "json", the array returns values

Comment: I just added   var textsLength = grid.jqGrid("getRowData"); instead of var textsLength = grid.jgGrid("getGridParam", "data"). I think it works out now.

Answer (score 2):

Reference from [JQGrid Doc](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods). I could understand that

> grid.jqGrid("getGridParam", "data")

will always return an empty array.Try to change the code as follows

> grid.jqGrid("getGridParam", "colModel")

I hope this will help you

Comment: @JayarajK  When I use grid.jqGrid("getGridParam", "data") where the datatype is "local" instead of "json", the array returns values.

Comment: @JayarajK I replaced data with colModel. But the same results.

Answer (score 0):

I just changed TO  `var textsLength = grid.jqGrid("getRowData");` FROM `var textsLength = grid.jgGrid("getGridParam", "data");` I think it works out now. –